# How can I dynamically create new variables/columns on databases in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to Stackoverflow and quite new to R. I would really appreciate your help.

I am using `dplyr`'s `mutate()` function to create a set new columns based on one initial column. For an a priori known number of columns to be created, everything works fine.

However, in my application, the number of new columns to be created is unknown (or rather determined as input parameter before running the code).

For illustration, consider the following minimal working example:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")

copy_to(con, mtcars, "mtcars", temporary = FALSE)

db <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
    select(carb) %>%
    distinct(carb) %>%
    arrange(carb) %>%
    mutate(carb1 = carb + 1) %>%
    mutate(carb2 = carb + 2) %>%
    mutate(carb3 = carb + 3) %>%
    show_query() %>%
    collect()
```

In this example, I create three new variables. However, I want the program to work with a dynamic number of variables (e.g., five or ten new variables). I also would like to do all of the calculations before `collect()`, because I want to copy the data into memory as late as possible.

Some background for my real life application: I want to use the [DB2's function ADD_MONTHS()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_addmonths.html). So I need `dplyr`/`dbplyr` to flush that function directly into an SQL command. I therefore need a solution that actually does not use data frame logic - I need the solution to be in `dplyr`.

From a different perspective: In SAS I'd use the macro processor to dynamically build a proc sql statement. Is there an equivalent in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfc(1:3, ~ df %>%
                  transmute(!! str_c('x', .x) := x + .x)) %>%
    bind_cols(df, .)
#  x x1 x2 x3
#1 1  2  3  4
#2 2  3  4  5
#3 3  4  5  6
```

---

In the case of database, do the `collect` before adding the columns

```
dat <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
        select(carb) %>%
        distinct(carb) %>%
        arrange(carb) %>%
        collect()
map_dfc(dat$carb, ~ dat %>%
                      transmute(!! str_c('carb', .x) := carb + .x)) %>%
    bind_cols(dat, .)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
#   carb carb1 carb2 carb3 carb4 carb6 carb8
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3     4     5     7     9
#2     2     3     4     5     6     8    10
#3     3     4     5     6     7     9    11
#4     4     5     6     7     8    10    12
#5     6     7     8     9    10    12    14
#6     8     9    10    11    12    14    16
```

---

Or another option if we want to do this before `collect`ing is to pass an expression in `mutate`

```
tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
   select(carb) %>%
   distinct(carb) %>%
   arrange(carb) %>%
   mutate(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(str_c('carb', 1:3, sep="+", collapse=";"))) %>%
   rename_at(-1, ~ str_c('carb', 1:3)) %>%
   show_query() %>%
   collect()
#<SQL>
#SELECT `carb`, `carb` + 1.0 AS `carb1`, `carb` + 2.0 AS `carb2`, `carb` + 3.0 AS #`carb3`
#FROM (SELECT *
#FROM (SELECT DISTINCT *
#FROM (SELECT `carb`
#FROM `mtcars`))
#ORDER BY `carb`)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#   carb carb1 carb2 carb3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3     4
#2     2     3     4     5
#3     3     4     5     6
#4     4     5     6     7
#5     6     7     8     9
#6     8     9    10    11
```

Comment: Hi akrun, 

thank you for your answer. Your example works if library(stringr) is added. 

Unfortunately, my example was too simplistic or rather poorly chosen. Instead of working with a data frame, I work with a database and cannot construct a data frame because I want to do calculations on a database. From my limited understanding of `purrr` and `map_dfc`, it only works with data frames. I constructed a new minimal working example that captures my problem better and edited my originally submitted question accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to do it before `collect()`? In my real-life I cannot copy the data into memory because it is quite large and I want to keep it in the database as long as possible.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2_dfc` from `purrr` pass the values to add and add data to original `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(df, map2_dfc(1:3, df ,`+`))

#  x V1 V2 V3
#1 1  2  3  4
#2 2  3  4  5
#3 3  4  5  6
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, 

thank you for your answer. The code works fine. 

Unfortunately, my example was too simplistic or rather poorly chosen. Instead of working with a data frame, I work with a database and cannot construct a data frame because I want to do calculations on a database. From my limited understanding of `purrr` and `map2_dfc`, it only works with data frames. I constructed a new minimal working example that captures my problem better and edited my originally submitted question accordingly.