# How can I dynamically build a string and pass it to dplyr's mutate() function in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I asked a similar question before ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440107/how-can-i-dynamically-create-new-variables-columns-on-databases-in-r-using-dplyr)). The given answer works fine. However, it turns out, that it does not fully apply to my use case.

Please consider the following minimal working example:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
library(stringr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")

copy_to(con, mtcars, "mtcars", temporary = FALSE)

db <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
    select(carb) %>%
    distinct(carb) %>%
    arrange(carb) %>% 
    mutate(Q1=1, Q2=2, Q3=3, Q4=4) %>% 
    collect()
```

I am interested in dynamically building the string `Q1=1, Q2=2, Q3=3, Q4=4` such that it could be `Q1=1, Q2=2, ..., Qn = n`.

One idea I had is to build the string like that:

```
n_par <- 4
str_c('Q', 1:n_par, ' = ', 1:n_par, collapse = ', ')
```

such that n_par could be any positive number. However, due to dplyr's non-standard evaluation, I cannot make it work like that. However, this is exactly what I need.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you tried unquoting the string?

Comment: I have tried several quoting and unquoting functions, but I could not make it work. However, my knowledge on this topic is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generating and evaluating the string**

`Q1 = 1, Q2 = 2, Q3 = 3, Q4 = 4` is not a string in the same way that `"Q1 = 1, Q2 = 2, Q3 = 3, Q4 = 4"` is a string. There are some R functions that will take a string object and evaluate it as code. For example:

```r
> eval(parse(text="print('hello world')"))

#> [1] "hello world"
```

However, this may not play nicely inside `dbplyr` translation. If you manage to get something like this approach working it would be good to see it posted as an answer.

**Using a loop**

Instead of doing it as a single string, an alternative is to use a loop:

```r
db <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
    select(carb) %>%
    distinct(carb) %>%
    arrange(carb)

for(i in 1:n){
    var = paste0("Q",i)
    db <- db %>%
        mutate(!!sym(var) := i)
}

db <- collect(db)
```

The `!!sym()` is required to tell `dplyr` that you want the text argument treated as a variable. Lazy evaluation can give you odd results without it. The `:=` assignment is required because the LHS needs to be evaluated.

This approach is roughly equivalent to one mutate statement for each variable (example below), but the `dbplyr` translation might not look as elegant as doing it all within a single mutate statement.

```r
db <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>%
    select(carb) %>%
    distinct(carb) %>%
    arrange(carb) %>%
    mutate(Q1 = 1) %>%
    mutate(Q2 = 2) %>%
    ...
    mutate(Qn = n) %>%
    collect()
```

Comment: The loop worked. I could even flush non-dplyr commands to the database that are native to the database. This is exactly what I need, thank you. I will play around a bit more with ``eval()`` and ``parse()`` and related functions and see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I recently read more about the topic and I found that the following code works quite nicely, causing dbplyr to write a cleaner SQL code.

```
# Libraries

library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

# Example database

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")

copy_to(con, mtcars, "mtcars", temporary = FALSE)

# Parameter for number of variables to be created

n <- 4 

# Variable list

var <- list() 
for(i in 1:n){
    j <- paste0("Q", i) 
    var[[j]] <- i
} 

# Query/computation

db <- tbl(con, "mtcars") %>% 
    select(carb) %>% 
    distinct(carb) %>% 
    arrange(carb) %>% 
    mutate(!!! var) %>% 
    show_query() %>% 
    collect()
```

The trick was to build a list with proper names and to put it into the `mutate()` function using `!!!`. Furthermore, I read that parsing and evaluating strings should be avoided, so I switched to lists.

Comment: A note for future users as I could not find this explained elsewhere. Missing the `!!!` inside the mutate gives the message "no applicable method ... for object of class call".

Answer (score 1):

Does this work in in your database?

```r
library(tidyverse)

q_n <- function(n) {
  str_c('Q', 1:n, ' = ', 1:n, collapse = ', ')
}

create_n_string <- function(data,n = 5,string = "Q"){
  data %>% 
    mutate(new_col = str_flatten(1:n,collapse = "_")) %>% 
    separate(new_col,into = string %>% str_c(1:n),sep = "_")
} 

mtcars %>% 
select(carb) %>%
  distinct(carb) %>%
  arrange(carb) %>%
  create_n_string()
#>   carb Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
#> 1    1  1  2  3  4  5
#> 2    2  1  2  3  4  5
#> 3    3  1  2  3  4  5
#> 4    4  1  2  3  4  5
#> 5    6  1  2  3  4  5
#> 6    8  1  2  3  4  5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768872/using-dplyr-sqlite-to-perform-un-nest-values-in-one-column-and-create-multiple it appears the separate command does not have a `dbplyr` translation.

Comment: The proposed code does not work for me. I get the error message:

``Error in separate(., new_col, into = string %>% str_c(1:n), sep = "_") : 
  could not find function "separate"``